# Arduino + SIM900 Module - Not getting the command response correctly

Tags: get, command, arduino, response

I'm having troubles getting the correct response from a SIM900 module, if I use the code as it is in the example it works just fine.

for this command:

```
void GetContacts(){
  mySerial.print("AT+CPBF=\"Mailbox\"");
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println();
}
```

and with this print code:

```
if (mySerial.available()){
  Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

I get:

```
AT+CPBF="Mailbox"

+CPBF: 1,"+584125089112",145,"Mailbox3"

+CPBF: 2,"+584264273127",145,"Mailbox1"

+CPBF: 3,"+584147373665",145,"Mailbox2"

OK
```

which is perfect, but if I try to read the output and then print it like this:

```
if (mySerial.available()){
  int intValue = mySerial.read();

  String stringOne;
  stringOne =  String(intValue, HEX); //int to HEX

  char charConversion;
  charConversion = hexNibbleToChar(stringOne[0]) * 16 + hexNibbleToChar(stringOne[1]); //HEX to Char
  contactString += charConversion;

  Serial.println(contactString);
}

char hexNibbleToChar(char nibble){
  if (nibble >= '0' && nibble <= '9')
    return nibble - '0';
  else if (nibble >= 'a' && nibble <= 'f')
    return 10 + nibble - 'a';
  else
    return 10 + nibble - 'A';
}
```

I get:

```
AT+CPBF="Mailbox"

+CPBF: 1,"+584125089112",145,"Mailbox3"

+CPBF: 2,"+58426
```

Suddenly stops there and I have no idea why, I've tried just reading and printing right after the int intValue = mySerial.read(); line, and when I convert the decimal string that I got there to char with any online converter the result it's the same.

Does any of you see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Juan Docal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for those of you with the same problem or something related, my solution was to save all the response in a String variable and then proccess it when the "mySerial" variable wasn't available anymore

```
String contactString = "";
if(mySerial.available()){
  contactString += (char) mySerial.read(); 
}
else{
  if(contactString != ""){
    //Process response
  }
  contactString = "";
}
```

I was proccessing all the data within mySerial.available() and somehow I was truncating the response...